# Can't access site over https using letsencrypt cert

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, letsencrypt

So we have [this](http://m.site.perkelle.com/) site (which is going to be replaced with a forum soon, therefore I need ssl) however when you [go to it using https](https://m.site.perkelle.com/) I time out. I am using apache2 on debian and have generated my SSL cert with getssl and letsencrypt. Here is my m.conf in my sites-enabled folder:

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName m.site.perkelle.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mc.site.perkelle.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mc.site.perkelle.com.access.log combined

    LogLevel warn

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mc.site.perkelle.com/mc.site.perkelle.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mc.site.perkelle.com/mc.site.perkelle.com.key

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/test/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you registered the certificate for the correct hostname? The certificate is registered for `mc.site.perkelle.com` but you are using it for `m.site.perkelle.com`.

Comment: @GiantTree Nice catch. Will generate a new one after dinner

Comment: Do you install the certificate manually? LetsEncrypt comes with an auto-installer for Apache that adds the needed lines to the file in `sites-available`.

Comment: Obvious question - Did you restart Apache since installing the cert?

Comment: Do you have a firewall?